# How can to return all my document in firestore to the list using flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to return all my documents in Firestore my document in Identifier based on the name but when I do my function its returns to me With the same number I have documents but the name its different instance of `DocumentSnapshot` but I need to return same names I have. How can I do this?

[image: image database]

```
Future getallDocument()async{
    final QuerySnapshot result = await Firestore.instance.collection("Institute").document(widget.id).collection("Ravs").getDocuments();
    final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;
    documents.forEach((data) {
        print(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot of your database structure? Also, maybe you could consider having somebody helping you out when redacting a question or even using an online [translator](https://translate.google.com/).

Comment: please check for my Question I post data base structure I need to get all document name in subcollcoation  I have How can I do this please help me

Comment: Could you clearly explain what you are trying to achieve? Could you show us also what documents/error message are you getting?

Comment: the result from my function print the list by name is instance of DocumentSnapshot  not the same documents names I have ..I'm trying to get all documents name into list view ...I'm sorry for my language English